# CodeEval Challenge Fizz Buzz

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java. The other day I saw a website providing challenges to solve online. Here is the code project I choose: [Fizz Buzz](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/1/)

This is where I am with the project:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    openFile(file);
    int[] line = new int[3];
    while (nextLine()) {
          try{


        line = readLine();
        String output = getLineOutput(line);
        System.out.println(output);
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e) { System.out.println("No such element exception"); }
    } 

}

static Scanner scan;

static void openFile(File file) {
    try {
        scan = new Scanner((file));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find file");
    }
}

static int[] readLine() {

    int a = scan.nextInt();

    int b = scan.nextInt();

    int c = scan.nextInt();

    int[] line;
    line = new int[] { a, b, c };

    return line;

}

static boolean nextLine() {
    return scan.hasNextLine();
}

static String getLineOutput(int[] line) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= line[2]; i++)
        if (i % line[0] == 0 && i % line[1] == 0) {
            sb.append("FB ");
        } else {
            if (i % line[0] == 0) {

                sb.append("F ");
            }
            if (i % line[1] == 0) {
                sb.append("B ");
            }
            if (i % line[0] > 0 && i % line[1] > 0) {
                sb.append(i + " ");
            }

        }
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

When I run the program in command prompt providing a path to a text file as the first argument my program seems to work fine. On CodeEval I get the following error:

CodeEval Error: Compilation was aborted after 10 seconds

Should I be accessing the file differently? Is there an exception I'm missing? None of my exceptions are prompting me.

Comment: *"CodeEval Error: Compilation was aborted after 10 seconds"* Nothing more? No message about the problem?

Comment: No, I did run an earlier version of the code where I was getting a NoSuchElementException but now this is all it gives me.

Comment: Btw your code also works for me. So the problem seem to be on that site. Different line endings (UNIX: CR; Windows: CR+LF) are also not a problem.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I solved the issue. I never closed the scanner so that was the problem.

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this helps anyone in the future this code doesn't close the scanner. Unfortunately on CodeEval the code doesn't execute if this is the case.

Adding `scan.close()` at the end of main method (after while loop solved) the issue.

Edit: code difference

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    openFile(file);
    int[] line = new int[3];
    while (nextLine()) {
          try{   
        line = readLine();
        String output = getLineOutput(line);
        System.out.println(output);
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e) { System.out.println("No such element exception"); }
    } 
    scan.close();

}
```

Comment: That's right, after the main methods while loop but still within the main method.